# Which sentence is correct? The first one or the second one?

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

Which sentence is correct? The first conditional or the second conditional?

**A: If I don't start packing soon, I will miss the flight.
If I didn't start packing soon, I would miss the flight.**

**B: Relax, it is still midday.**

I know that the first conditional is used to talk about things that are possible in the future while the second conditional is used to talk about things which are unreal or imaginary.

Comment: The answer you were given on ELU explains this adequately. The first sentence is natural if you need to start packing for a journey; the second is grammatical but only makes sense if it refers to a situation in the past.

Comment: Kate Bunting, It refers to a situation in the present, not a situation in the past.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, The second sentence seems to be Conditional Type 2, so why do you say it can make sense if it refers to a situation in the past. it can't make sense in the past. As a Conditianl Type 2 sentence, It can only refer to something that is hypotetchical. If it had been a situation in the past, the sentence would have been:  "If I hadn't started packing soon enough, I would have miss the flight."

Comment: @yunus - Your version is incorrect - it should be "If I hadn't started packing soon (early?) enough, I would have **missed** the flight." My interpretation imagines a first-person narrator looking back at a past situation - at the time they would have thought "If I don't start packing...", but telling the story in the present, they say "If I didn't start packing...".

Answer (score 1):

Correct: If I don't start packing soon, I will miss the flight. (First Conditional)

It refers to a possible future action.

Second Conditional-

The if-clause is in the simple past tense. But The meaning is present, not past.

It refers to something unreal/imaginary.

If I *knew* his number, I would phone him. (I don't know his number)

If I *were* rich, I would help him. (I am not rich)

If I won the lottery, I would buy a car.